# How do I prevent cursor from placing itself at the beginning of EditText when clicked

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an `EditText pageTitle` and its behavior is dependent on its `onFocusListener` and `onClickListener` and another method `setListenerToRootView()` which detects if the soft keyboard is shown or hidden. The issue is whenever I click `pageTitle`, the cursor is automatically placed at the beginning. I am suspecting `setListenerToRootView()` is responsible for this bug since issue fixes itself when I remove this method.

However, I do need this method since another view's visibility (`saveCancelBar`) depends on the soft keyboard's visibility. Is there any way that I can keep this method but make sure that when the user clicks `pageTitle`, the cursor will be placed on the exact position that he clicked (not the beginning)?

Comment: Please never post ephemeral content like paste.ofcode.org on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `setSelection()` for selecting the last position programatically.
in `onClick` and `onFocus` use **setSelection**

```
        editTextName.setSelection(editTextName.getText().length());
```

Comment: What I meant was your solution is not my intended behavior. Your solution places the cursor at the end of the string/text on the first click of the `EditText`. What I want is to place the cursor exactly where the user clicked the `EditText` (e.g. `EditText` contains the string "sample" and user clicks somewhere between 'a' and 'm', the cursor (or the blinking '|') appears between 'a' and 'm'.

Comment: I may have to look into the behavior of the `setListenerToRoot()` method since it is obviously the culprit.